# JHipster - User changelog generated every time, on fresh project

Tags: jhipster, liquibase

I have tried to create a new project with JHIpster version 7.9.3 (but the same problem appears with previous versions and with new 8 beta versions).

The project is a simple Monolithic project, skipping client generation with a MySQL database.

After i've generated the project and database (with initial changelog), every time i try to execute `liquibase:diff`, i found a changelog like this:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xmlns:pro="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-latest.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-latest.xsd">
    <changeSet author="nicola (generated)" id="1689327530838-1">
        <dropUniqueConstraint constraintName="UC_JHI_USERLOGIN_COL" tableName="jhi_user"/>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="nicola (generated)" id="1689327530838-2">
        <addUniqueConstraint columnNames="login" constraintName="UC_JHI_USERLOGIN_COL" tableName="jhi_user"/>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

What's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

I'm expecting an empty change log, if the entities remain the sames.

Comment: Have you considered using `--incremental-changelog` option?

Comment: hi  Gaël, can you explain how to use this option? I didn't find it on liquibase:diff helper command

Comment: It's an option of jhipster not of liquibase.

Comment: oops sorry I didn't know this option, the helper doesn't write anything about it. How does it work?

Comment: anyway, could be a liquibase related problem?

Comment: No, please read https://entando.com/page/en/how_to_use_liquibase_to_update_the_schema_of_your_jhipster_application?contentId=BLG5325&modelId=64

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but the article said to use `./mvnw liquibase:diff` that is the command that i'm already use.

Comment: Not really or you read only the JHipster 6 part, the JHipster 7 part does not use liquibase maven plugin at all.